# How to enable additional logging when running `hadoop fs` with MAPRFS?

Tags: hadoop, docker, mapr

When I run this command:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /tmp/1GB.img 'maprfs://maprfs.example.com/tmp/1GB.img'
```

I get the following errors.

```
2014-11-05 01:21:08,7669 ERROR Client fs/client/fileclient/cc/writebuf.cc:154 Thread: 240 FlushWrite failed: File 1GB.img, error: Invalid argument(22), pfid 4484.66.266002, off 65536, fid 5189.87.131376
14/11/05 01:21:08 ERROR fs.Inode: Write failed for file: /tmp/1GB.img, error: Invalid argument
14/11/05 01:21:08 ERROR fs.Inode: Marking failure for: /tmp/1GB.img, error: Invalid argument
14/11/05 01:21:08 ERROR fs.Inode: Throwing exception for: /tmp/1GB.img, error: Invalid argument
14/11/05 01:21:08 ERROR fs.Inode: Flush failed for file: /tmp/1GB.img, error: Invalid argument
14/11/05 01:21:08 ERROR fs.Inode: Marking failure for: /tmp/1GB.img, error: Invalid argument
14/11/05 01:21:08 ERROR fs.Inode: Throwing exception for: /tmp/1GB.img, error: Invalid argument
copyFromLocal: 4484.66.266002 /tmp/1GB.img (Invalid argument)
```

Can anyone suggest how to enable additional verbose/debug logging?

The above errors seem to be coming from the MAPR hadoop classes. It would be nice to enable more verbose logging in those packages, as well as org.apache.*

I tried modifying /opt/mapr/conf/logging.properties but it didn't seem to help.

BTW, running Hadoop 1.0.3 and MapR 3.1.1.26113.GA

thanks,

Fi

p.s.
This is related to my question at http://answers.mapr.com/questions/11374/write-to-maprfs-with-hadoop-cli-fails-inside-docker-while-running-on-a-data-node#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the option directly

`hadoop mfs -Dfs.mapr.trace=DEBUG -ls maprfs://maprfs.example.com/tmp/1GB.img`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, courtesy of http://answers.mapr.com/answer_link/6181/

Just need a `fs.mapr.trace=debug` property in

`/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/conf/core-site.xml`

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.mapr.trace</name>
    <value>debug</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```